# How do large image services store their images efficiently?

Tags: image, compression, cloud, storage

While I understand most image files cannot be further compressed, how do large image services like imgur, flickr store their images? Do they simple dump everything into the file system then index it with db? Or do they compress multiple images into a more efficient package?

Comment: This might be a good link to take a look at: http://highscalability.com/flickr-architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into HayStack for large applications, uploading into a file system then storing into a DB would be sufficient for smaller applications even up to millions. However, larger companies such as flickr use haystack objects.